# Seq2Seq model doesn't learn sentence structure

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

The following code is a Seq2Seq conversational language model. The training data is an input followed by an output. The input encoder has no SOS and EOS tokens, the input decoder has no SOS tokens and the output decoder has both tokens (the input decoder is just the output but shifted left once to have it predict the next word, called the "target output"). The problem with my model is that the output doesn't form coherent sentences, just random words. Here are what I believe to be the important parts of the code.

````
BATCH_SIZE = 32
EMBEDDING_DIM = 256
RNN_UNITS = 1024
EPOCHS = 1000

x_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x)
y_tar_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(y_tar)
y_out_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(y_out)

max_seq_length = max(max(len(seq) for seq in x_seq), max(len(seq) for seq in y_out_seq))

x_seq = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_seq, maxlen=max_seq_length, padding='post')
y_tar_seq = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(y_tar_seq, maxlen=max_seq_length, padding='post')
y_out_seq = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(y_out_seq, maxlen=max_seq_length, padding='post')

input_encoder = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
input_decoder = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
output_decoder = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))

encoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM)(input_encoder)
encoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(RNN_UNITS, return_state=True, dropout=0.2)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_embedding)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

decoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM)(input_decoder)
decoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(RNN_UNITS, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, dropout=0.2)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_embedding, initial_state=encoder_states)

decoder_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')
output = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

model = tf.keras.models.Model([input_encoder, input_decoder, output_decoder], output)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False))

history = model.fit([x_seq, y_out_seq, y_tar_seq], y_out_seq, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, validation_split=0.2)

def generate_response(question):
    response = [[tokenizer.word_index['sos']]]
    response = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(response, maxlen=max_seq_length, padding='pre')
    question_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(question.split())
    question_seq = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(question_seq, maxlen=max_seq_length, padding='pre')

    question_seq = np.expand_dims(question_seq[0], axis=0)
    dummy_output = np.zeros_like(response)

    for i in range(max_seq_length-1):
        pred = model.predict([question_seq, response, dummy_output])
        pred_id = np.argmax(pred[:, i, 1:])
        if pred_id == tokenizer.word_index['eos']:
            break
        response[0] = np.roll(response[0], -1)
        response[0][-1] = pred_id
    return ' '.join([tokenizer.index_word[idx] for idx in response[0]])```
````

Comment: _the input decoder has no SOS tokens and the output decoder has both tokens_ does not sound right to me... say you encoded the input, then you provide an input to the decoder, which by your description seems to be the first word of the output, but the decoder has to regress the SOS token... instead it should be the opposite, you give the SOS token to the decoder, and you regress the first word

Comment: thanks, that is correct. That is one mistake fixed, yet the output still doesn't resemble the training data. So there is still things to improve